# python3 json.loads(response.decode('utf-8')) UnicodeDecodeError:

Tags: json, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, iot

the python script is :

```
    while True: 

    TS = urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds/last.json?api_key=%s"
% (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))

response = TS.read()

data = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))

a = data['created_at'] b = data['field1'] c = data['field2'] z = float(b)

print (a + " "+ "Soil_Moisture = "+ b + " " + "Temprature = " + c + " ")
```

when i run on google colab it works, when i run on raspberry pi3 this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/Desktop/m.py", line 19, in data = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8')) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

i got it working like month a go but i dont recall making any changes to the script! not sure what went wrong. would appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. The issue was the hotspot had three devices connected on it. for some reason the raspberry pi stop connecting when this happens even though it shows it had connection signal. I had to disconnect other devices and it worked.